# How to dynamically generate row color in XSL:FO without xsl:for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, tablerow

I have a single data set with varying list of the attributes(about 15), like displayed below.

Sample Data 1:

```
<cd>
  <name>Tom</name>
  <address>Madison Square</address>
  <phone>000-000-0000</phone>
</cd>
```

Sample Data 2:

```
<cd>
  <name>Tom</name>
  <city>New York</city>
  <phone>000-000-0000</phone>
</cd>
```

Complete list of attributes(subset):

```
<cd>
   <name>xxx</name>
   <address>xxxx</address>
   <city>xxxx</city>
   <phone>000-000-0000</phone>
</cd>
```

I want to build a fo:table with alternate row colors for this dynamic table. I have tried using xsl:for-each and position(), but it doesn't work. Is there a way to get previous row properties like, color? Any suggestions.

Added code for reference:

```
        <fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt" padding-top="8pt">
              <fo:block> <xsl:value-of select="cd/name"/></fo:block>               
           </fo:table-cell>
         </fo:table-row>
         <xsl:if test="normalize-space(cd/address) !=''">
           <fo:table-row background-color="#EEF0F2" >
             <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt" padding-top="8pt">
               <fo:block> <xsl:value-of select="cd/address"/></fo:block>                   
             </fo:table-cell>
           </fo:table-row>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="normalize-space(cd/city) !=''">
           <fo:table-row background-color="#EEF0F2" >
             <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt" padding-top="8pt">
              <fo:block> <xsl:value-of select="cd/city"/></fo:block>                  
             </fo:table-cell>
           </fo:table-row>            
         </xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted code example is not quite enough. We have no idea of context. Something reproducible (something we could run) would be ideal.

Here's a generic answer that should help though.

What you can do is use `xsl:apply-templates` to process the children of `cd` that aren't empty. This changes the node set that's being processed and will allow `position()` to work properly.

*Note: You could also do this with `xsl:for-each`. However, if you're transforming anything but the most simple XML to a very simple XSL-FO you're better off using a push approach rather than a pull approach. This will make your XSLT much easier to maintain and scale.*

You can then use `mod` to see if the position is divisible by 2. If it is, add the background-color.

Example:

**XML Input**

```
<cd>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <address>xxxx</address>
    <city>xxx</city>
    <whatevs></whatevs>
    <phone>000-000-0000</phone>
</cd>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
                    <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body"> 
                    <fo:table>
                        <fo:table-body>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="cd/*[string()]"/>                            
                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cd/*">
        <fo:table-row>            
            <xsl:if test="position() mod 2">
                <xsl:attribute name="background-color">
                    <xsl:text>#EEF0F2</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt" padding-top="8pt">
                <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:block>                  
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSL-FO Output**

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
         <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:table>
            <fo:table-body>
               <fo:table-row background-color="#EEF0F2">
                  <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt" padding-top="8pt">
                     <fo:block>xxx</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
               </fo:table-row>
               <fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt" padding-top="8pt">
                     <fo:block>xxxx</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
               </fo:table-row>
               <fo:table-row background-color="#EEF0F2">
                  <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt" padding-top="8pt">
                     <fo:block>xxx</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
               </fo:table-row>
               <fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt" padding-top="8pt">
                     <fo:block>000-000-0000</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
               </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
         </fo:table>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

**Rendered PDF** (used FOP 1.1)

[image]

Comment: This option solved my problem! I will update the whole code later today

Answer (score 0):

Post your code. One strategy in such cases would be to first build the table in a variable, and then copy it to output, adding the color tag while you do. This might be less messy.